# How to move all files (excluding sub-directories) from one directory to another?

Tags: shell-script, files, move

How do you move all the files (excluding sub-directories) from one directory to another. I'd prefer if the solution used just basic shell scripting.

Comment: What have you tried? What is not working? Do you have some files that `mv src/dir/* dst/dir/` not take along?

Comment: I think this is most stupid non-feature in the whole linux universe. To write a script to move a file.. what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy way:

```
for f in /some/path/*; do
    if [ -f "$f" ]; then
        mv "$f" /some/other/path
    fi
done
```

The slightly more complicated way:

```
find /some/path -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv {} /dome/other/path \;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} mv {} /path/to/target/directory/{}
```

This will also deal with filenames containing newlines.

Answer (score 0):

```
cd $src
mv `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf '%f\n'` $tgt
```

should do it, where  `$src`is your source folder and `$tgt` is your target folder

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd $SOURCE_DIR
$ mv `ls -p| grep -v /` $Target_dir
```

Execution Steps

1. Move to Source directory using cd command.
2. ls -p suffixes "/" to all the directories.
3. grep -v is used exclude the directories and to get the regular file.
4. Finally moving all the files to the target directory.

Comment: Don't do `mv \`....\` ....`. Use the `find` command instead. What you wrote is extremely hackish.

Comment: why is it hackish?